# Javascript,getTime()

Tags: javascript, gettime

I am trying to understand something about `getTime()`,
My problem is that,
I am setting up a **new Date** with lets say: **23,07,2012**.
When I am using `getTime()` on it I should get the milliseconds Since **01,01,1970.**
When I divide the value I getting from `getTime()` with **(1000*60*60*24)** I should get the days number was pass since **01,01,1970** until **05,07,2012** but somehow I get a number with a Decimal point **(15543.875)** I dont understand why, I mean since **01,01,1970** and **23,07,2012** I should get an integer(that what I think), well I know I am really wrong, if can someone please help me understand why the decimal point at the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting a date like `new Date(2012, 06, 23)` It will be set according to the timezone of the client, where as `.getTime()` is `UTC`. You want [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```
Date.UTC(2012,6,23) / (1000*60*60*24)
//15544 For any computer

new Date(2012, 06, 23) / (1000*60*60*24)
//15543.875 For my computer, I am coincidentally in  the same timezone as Israel. This result will depend on what timezone the client is.
```

Comment: thank you esailija can you please upload a code showing resoult of my timezone and the UTC timezone devide with (1000*60*60*24) becouse the link is not working and i cant write the code down its not working mabye i didnt got you right so if you can please upload thank you.

Comment: @uBlankText all the code you need is in my answer. Show me your non-working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So the decimal point is becouse my timezone is falling behind in few hours and that why i should use the ceil method or the UTC?

Comment: @uBlankText you should only use the `UTC`. The decimal point is just a symptom, the real cause is the timezones which you can ignore when you use `UTC`. So use `UTC`.